# How is the Q value translated to action in DRL framework presented in Gu, Shixiang et al (2016)

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning, real-time

I was reading the paper [*Deep Reinforcement Learning for Robotic Manipulation with Asynchronous Off-Policy Updates*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.00633) and I kind of understand everything. The results also seem very interesting, enabling fast learning in real-time for complex tasks in a real environment.

In any case, I've been struggling to understand how the Q-value calculated is translated in this case to an action(this is, the angular speed of the joints, or desired joint position, ...) , especially since they are working in a continuous space, and not a discrete space, which is what I usually see when I read about or work in RL Q-Learning.

Answer (score 0):

In the discrete case where there are $n$ actions, the typical setup is to have a neural network $f: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ which computes the Q-values of all actions at once.

In the continuous case, it isn't possible to enumerate all actions, so $f : S\times A \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ only computes the value of a single state-action pair.

It's often desireable to compute a "greedy policy" corresponding to a Q function estimator, that is, $\pi(s) = \text{argmax}_{a \in A} \hat{Q}(s, a)$. This is difficult in the continuous case because we'd probably have to make many queries to our neural network $f$ in order to find a good approximation of this maximum.

Instead, actor critic algorithms get around this by using a separate policy network for rollouts, to avoid having to compute greedy policies. You can read more about DDPG [here](https://spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/algorithms/ddpg.html). (DDPG is a specific instance of actor-critic).